# How To Label Colormaps in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, legend, colormap

I have the following image derived from imagesc(some matrix whose entries correspond to those colors). The Cyan and the Yellow both mean different things. I would like to either:

1. Add a legend where I can fill in what each color means
2. Segregate parts of the X-axis to where I can type "cyan" on the x region below the cyan part, and "yellow" on the x region below the yellow part.

Either or would be fine, and which ever one is easier would be appropriate for me.

[image]

```
                CYAN                         YELLOW
```

Comment: Could you maybe create an illustration showing what you want to achieve? (i.e. put text labels where you want text to be)

Comment: Several questions: does your image always consist of 2 parts? Do you know what you are going to write in the labels in advance, or do you want the text to be an editable field? For the text below the figure, did you try [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html)? As for the legend, I suppose you can plot a single point (styled as a filled square marker the same color as the containing region) on each of the colored regions and just display a legend normally...

Comment: No, sometimes, my image has up to 7 parts. I want the labels to sort of be centered around the color region.

Comment: That's why I asked you for an illustration... I meant open this image in Paint Brush or you OS equivalent and show us what the end result should look like, with difficult inputs (i.e. 6-7 colors)! Are they always horizontally spaced? Also, do they always appear in the same order?

Comment: so @AlvinNunez does any f the answer below helped you? If so please accept one of them; if not please tell us. Thanks!

Comment: I apologize, these answers are great, I selected one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option, which happens to be [matlab-hg2](/questions/tagged/matlab-hg2) friendly:

```
%% // Initialization
clear variables; close all force; clc;
%% // Generate some data
fakeData = magic(3)-0.5;
fakeData_horz = fakeData(:)'; %//'
fakeNames = cellstr(strcat('color',num2str((1:9)'))); %//'
fakeNameMapping = fakeNames(randperm(numel(fakeData)));
%% // Create figure
hFig = figure('Position',[680,488,758,610],'Resize','off');

%% // Top left example
cLims = [0 numel(fakeData)+1];
hSp = subplot(2,2,1); 
imagesc(fakeData); axis image; set(hSp,'XTick',[],'YTick',[]);
colorbar; caxis(cLims); 
[XX,YY] = meshgrid(1:size(fakeData,1),1:size(fakeData,2));
text(XX(:),YY(:),fakeNameMapping,'HorizontalAlignment','center');

%% // Bottom example
hSp = subplot(2,2,3:4);
cLims = [0 numel(fakeData)+1]; %Not required here since unchanged
imagesc(fakeData_horz); axis image; set(hSp,'XTick',[],'YTick',[]);
colorbar; caxis(cLims); 
drawnow; %// This command will allow the annotations to be positioned properly
for ind1=1:numel(fakeData_horz)
    newPos = [hSp.Position(1)+hSp.Position(3)/numel(fakeData_horz) * (ind1-1),...
              hSp.Position(2)*1.6,... %1.6 is chosen for the demo
              hSp.Position(3)/numel(fakeData_horz),...
              0.05]; % 0.05 is chosen for the demo; play around with it
    h= annotation('textbox',newPos,'String',fakeNameMapping{ind1},...
        'LineStyle','none','HorizontalAlignment','center');
end

%% // Top right example
hSp = subplot(2,2,2);
cLims = [0 numel(fakeData)]; %// cLims is a bit different here!
imagesc(fakeData); axis image; set(hSp,'XTick',[],'YTick',[]);
caxis(hSp,cLims); colormap(hSp,parula(numel(fakeData)));
cb = colorbar; %// This time we need a handle to the colorbar
cb.Ticks = (hSp.CLim(1):hSp.CLim(2))+0.5; %// Set the tick positions
cb.TickLabels = fakeNames; %// Set the tick strings
```

Which results in:
[image]

Note: unless using a more intelligent text positioning computation, the figure's size should not be changed after it was plotted (in the 2nd example), because then the text no longer remains where it should be.

---

Edit: added another option where only the colorbar is labeled.

Comment: Wow very nice and much more elegant than mine! +1 :)

Comment: @Benoit_11 - Thanks, I appreciate the kind words!

Comment: Dev-iL, is there anyway I can make the bottom plot, "larger"?

Comment: @AlvinNunez 1) Don't use subplot; 2) Specify larger width and height in `hFig = figure('Position',[680,488,758,610],'Resize','off');`

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this? It's very basic haha.

```
clc
clear
close all

%// Dummy array
A = repmat([0 0 0 1 1 1],6,1);

imagesc(A)

hold on

%// Dummy data to add legend
scatter(0,0,1,'b','filled')
scatter(0,0,1,'r','filled')

axis off
colorbar

%// Get axis coordinates (x first and then y)
ax = axis;

%// Add text. You can easily adjust the x-offset depending on how many colors you have.
text(ax(2)/4+ax(1),ax(4)+.2,'Blue','Color','b','FontSize',20,'HorizontalAlignment','Center')
text(3*ax(2)/4+.2,ax(4)+.2,'Red','Color','r','FontSize',20,'HorizontalAlignment','Center')

%// Add legend
legend({'Blue';'Red'})
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I should dub you the plot king.